# How validate FormArray control in Angular 6

Tags: angular, validation, angular7, angular4-forms, formarray

My HTML looks like this -

```
<form name="add_stepform" [formGroup]="ActionTypeForm" novalidate>
      <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize]="100" class="stepViewPort">
        <div [@fadeInOut] class="TestSteps example-item" 
             *cdkVirtualFor="let step of listOfSteps;TemplateCacheSize:0 let i=index">
          <div formArrayName="steps">
            <div [formGroupName]="i">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="font16">Step Description</label>
                  <input id="stepDescription" type="text"
                    formControlName="stepDescription" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="ex: about the application" >
                    <mat-error *ngIf="stepDescription.errors?.required">
                        Description Required<br>
                    </mat-error>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport></form>
```

.ts file -

```
this.ActionTypeForm = new FormGroup({
  steps: new FormArray([this.testSteps()])})

testSteps() {
return new FormGroup({
  stepDescription: new FormControl('', [Validators.required)}
  get stepDescription(){
  return ((<FormArray>this.ActionTypeForm.get('steps')).controls)[0].get('stepDescription')
}
```

but its validating only first step description .. So any idea how to dynamically using index value ??

Comment: If possible then provide a stackblitz!

Comment: If you only has one error (required) you can remove the *ngIf and left the mat error like `<mat-error>Description Required<br></mat-error>` else you can use in the .html  or pass as argument the "i" to a function `step.get('stepDescription').errors?.required` or `ActionTypeForm.get('steps').at(i).get('stepDescription').errors?.required`

Comment: hi @Eliseo Thanks for the solution .. it worked for me  !! it was pretty simple  :) Thanks a ton !

Comment: @Eliseo do u have any idea how to validate input not to  accept single quote or dobule quote as input ???

Comment: I supouse you can achieve using the angular pattern validation -is using a 'regExp'- https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern